# Prevent database (psql) to show error on REST api

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest

I am currently implementing a REST API with NodeJS. However I am wondering how I can prevent database errors, for instance when I insert a row again, which is against the constraints rules.

My code would look like this:

```
router.put("/like/:id", async (req, res) => {

  const id = req.params.id;
  const liked = req.body.liked;
  const user = req.body.user;


  const result = await db.query(
    "INSERT INTO abc (t_id, m_id) VALUES ($1,$2)",
    [id, user.id]
  );


  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

So when someone access the route `/like/1` the second time I get:

```
error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

I am currently logging the database errors, the app doesn't crash, but I wonder how I can make it better. I think my main question is: Do I have to query the database first, before inserting, to prevent errors? This will work but it will also slow down the app a little more, because there is an additional query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a query to check whether a record already exists which I think won't lead to any big performance issue. You can also look for `UPSERT` query:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/.

So if you want to avoid DB error either write an extra query or do upsert. 
If you want to avoid extra query Upsert would be the best Choice.

Use try-catch block to handle error

```
router.put("/like/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const liked = req.body.liked;
  const user = req.body.user;



try {
      // upsert query1 with no update
      let query = "INSERT INTO abc (t_id,m_id) VALUES ($1,$2) ON CONFLICT (t_id) 
      DO NOTHING";
       /* query with update 
        "INSERT INTO abc (t_id,m_id) VALUES ($1,$2) ON CONFLICT ( 
        t_id) UPDATE SET t_id = {{t_id}}"
      */
       const result = await db.query(
        query,
        [id, user.id]
      );
       res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch (err) {
         // handle error here with a custom error message
           res.status(400).send({msg:"any message"});
   }
```

});

Comment: This will still cause a database error, but the app won't crash. The app doesn't crash anyway, since I prevented this like I said. But I think my main question is: How do I handle such a situation, to prevent a database error. Is it nescessary to check the database row first before I insert it?